# How to execute several different count aggregations within one query

Tags: mysql

I'm executing query, that has to select count(*) output and the insert result into another table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (stopped) SELECT count(*) 
FROM db2.table2 WHERE condition=2;
```

However, I need this query to count outputs according to the different conditions. How I can combine all my queries like these to **one query**?

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (active) SELECT count(*) 
FROM db2.table2 WHERE condition=1;
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (susp) SELECT count(*) 
FROM db2.table2 WHERE condition=2 and option=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `union all`

```
SELECT count(*)  as cnt FROM db2.table2 WHERE condition=2
union all
SELECT count(*) FROM db2.table2 WHERE condition=1
union all 
SELECT count(*) FROM db2.table2 WHERE condition=2 and option=4
```